# Setting up One-to-Many relationship in sqlalchemy, but keep getting AmbiguousForeignKeysError

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to set up a one-to-many relation between two tables (User and BlogPost, respectively).
I tried copying what the course(?) solution for this and still get foreign-key errors.  What do I have wrong? Or, is this actually an issue with sqlalchemy (v. 1.3.19)?

I've even tried upgrading to the current version (1.4.31) with no success.  I was getting run-time errors (flask page error reports) usually around the `posts = BlogPost.query.all()` line in `home()`.  Now that I've upgraded the package, I'm getting a build-time error (`AttributeError: can't set attribute`) stemming from the `db.create_all()` line.

I've also tried deleting the db, again with no success.

Please leave a comment if this was answered somewhere else or if more info is needed.

Here's a snippet from **Main.py:**

```py
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

    posts = relationship("BlogPost", back_populates="author")


class BlogPost(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "blog_posts"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.id"))
    title = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=True, nullable=False)
    subtitle = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    body = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    img_url = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.id"))

    author = relationship("User", back_populates="posts")

db.create_all()

@app.route('/')
def home():
    posts = BlogPost.query.all()
    user = current_user
    return render_template("index.html", all_posts=posts, user=user)
```

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know what's wrong, but the following code works in a newer project.  Like I said in one of the comments: I suspect that there's an issue with my current PyCharm project.

```py
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100))
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    posts = relationship("BlogPost", back_populates="author")


class BlogPost(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "blog_posts"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.id"))
    author = relationship("User", back_populates="posts")
    title = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=True, nullable=False)
    subtitle = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    body = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    img_url = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)

db.create_all()

@app.route('/')
def home():
    posts = BlogPost.query.all()
    return render_template("index.html", all_posts=posts)
```